# Transferring Fingerprint image from android to PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-fingerprint-api

I am working on attendance application using Android, PHP and MySQL, I want to transfer the result of the fingerprint scan capture to PHP then match the result of the fingerprint scan capture in the database if the fingerprint result is already register in the database then it will return and say successful and then if the attendance is successful, the data from android device will directly import into MySQL database through PHP script.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question states what you want to accomplish, but not what you're having problems with. Could you let us know how far your project got, and what specific programming problem you're now running into?

Comment: i dont know how to send the fingerprint scan capture from android device to php to check if the fingerprint is already registered in the system..

Comment: Ok, so what software do you have to access a scanned fingerprint on Andriod? Does this work?

Comment: we would like to use android studio to access it.. it will be possible ? we will use android phone marshmallow version for the finger print scanner of the phone because we will use the android phone to scan the fingerprint of the students.. the problem is we dont know how can we transfer the fingerprint capture to the php My SQL database to read the fingerprint if the fingerprint is all ready registered in the database.. and also are problem is if we can save the fingerprint capture from android device to MySQL.. in our research we dont have seen any prof that our study is totally exiting..

Comment: As far as I can tell, and I am not an expert, android phones do not give you access to the fingerprint sensor directly. You have to use a special API or SDK. These are aimed at authenticating the phone user, not at giving you the raw image of the fingerprint. I even believe that hardware companies block access to this hardware intentionally, to prevent anyone from collecting fingerprints using their hardware. That makes perfect sense. It would be a huge infringement on our privacy if phone apps were used to collect our fingerprints.

Comment: if we use API or SDK it is possible that we create it?

Comment: As I said: I think 'it' is not possible.

Comment: if theirs other way to create it?